# ui-router nested view doesn't get loaded properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hey I have a simple app which I have created.

The app has the following views

1.**Settings** - Main View.

2.**Profile** - Sub view, child of Settings View.

3.**Account** - Sub View, child of Settings View.

I want the application to start from profile page, therefore I wrote the following code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profile');
```

But apparently noting is happen, I got a **blank screen** and can't see the view properly(settings.profile).

I have added my code to a plunker to make things more convenient and accessible for other developers which can help me solve my problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/RFP5dUNV876cy8vRDuvL?p=preview

Main main code is like this:

```
/**
*  Module
*
* Description
*/
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title="Index Page";
}]);

app.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title="Profile Page";
}]);

app.controller('AccountController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title="Account Page";
}]);

app.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title="Settings Page";
}]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsController'
        })
        .state('settings.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        })
        .state('settings.account', {
            url: '/account',
            templateUrl: 'account.html',
            controller: 'AccountController'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profile');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.otherwise` function to:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings/profile');
```

Since the other routes are nested within `settings` state, you can only access the nested views via the `<ui-view>` in `settings.html`. The urls are also nested within each other if `url` parameter is defined in both, so `/settings/profile` is required.

[Updated Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MAwmxTup7OsjiiENPknz?p=preview)

Comment: but I don't want to do that, I want it to load the nested view at first.

Comment: Whoops, noticed my mistake. Updated to account for nested urls. Updated plnkr link as well